# How do I pass a dynamic list of a viewmodel from view to controller?

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, view, viewmodel

I am building a logistics application where warehouse items are logged in a database with CRUD functionality.

I am now stuck with an issue of editing amount of stocked inventory in a given warehouse, where I am trying to dynamically generate a list of a ViewModel (with  for input), and post the edited input to a [HttpPost] method. The list of divs generates as it should in the view, but the edited input does not pass into my controller method. I managed to pass it before but edited the code and restarted the application so I know I'm close. What am I doing wrong?

Since the ViewModel inherits properties from other classes I also guess it needs to be of model type IEnumerable<> in the view.

**Class:**

```
public class LagerSaldoVM
    {
        public string Lager { get; set; }
        public string Produkt { get; set; }
        public int Saldo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Produkt> Produkter { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Fardigvarulager> Lagerhus { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller method [HttpGet]:**

```
public IActionResult Edit(int LagerID)
        {
            List<LagerSaldoVM> ls = new List<LagerSaldoVM>();
            string error = "";
            LagerSaldoMetod lsm = new LagerSaldoMetod();
            ls = lsm.getLagerSaldoFor(LagerID, out error);
            ViewBag.LagerID = LagerID;
            foreach (var item in ls)
            {
                ViewBag.Lager = item.Lager;
            }

            return View(ls);
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<LagerSaldoVM>

<body>
    <h1 class="rubrik">Ändra saldo för @ViewBag.Lager</h1>
    <div class="editBox">
        <form method="post" asp-action="EditPost" asp-route-LagerID="@ViewBag.LagerID">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@item.Produkt" class="control-label">@item.Produkt</label>
                    <input asp-for="@item.Saldo" class="form-control" placeholder="@item.Saldo" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@item.Saldo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Uppdatera lager" class="update" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller method [HttpPost]:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult EditPost(int LagerID, List<LagerSaldoVM> ls)
        {
            string error = "";
            Debug.WriteLine(LagerID);
            Debug.WriteLine(LagerID);
            Debug.WriteLine(LagerID);

            LagerSaldoMetod lsm = new LagerSaldoMetod();
            
            foreach (var item in ls)
            {
                //lsm.updateLagerSaldo(LagerID, item.Produkt, item.Saldo, error);
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Saldo);
                Debug.WriteLine(item.Saldo);

            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Im guessing it has something to do with binding the data in the view to the List I'm trying to pass ass argument in my Post method. I have not yet found an answer which resolves this issue using a foreach loop, preferably without LINQ, and with a dynamically loaded view.

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have fixed it by exchanging model type IEnumerable to List and using the index of the model to manipulate listed properties.

**This updated view solved it:**

```
@model List<LagerSaldoVM>

<body>
    <h1 class="rubrik">Ändra saldo för @ViewBag.Lager</h1>
    <div class="editBox">
        <form asp-action="EditPost" asp-route-LagerID="@ViewBag.LagerID">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model[i].Produkt" class="control-label">@Model[i].Produkt</label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].Saldo" class="form-control" placeholder="@Model[i].Saldo" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model[i].Saldo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Uppdatera lager" class="update" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```